# Threading error while using LiveChart

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, livecharts

I'm trying to use [LiveCharts](https://lvcharts.net) CartesianChart in a winforms application.
When I try to run the application this error comes up:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll
>
> Additional information: The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.

on line containing `this.cartesianChart1 = new LiveCharts.WinForms.CartesianChart();` in Form.Designer.cs inside the `InitializeComponent()` function.

Any way to solve this?

Comment: include `threadName.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);` where you have created a thread instance

Comment: I haven't created any thread instance. I just dragged the control on to the form and pressed 'Run'.

Answer (score 0):

you need to run it from a new thread and set the apartment state to STA:

```
 TaskCompletionSource<T> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
        Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                tcs.SetResult(func());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                tcs.SetException(e);
            }
        });
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
```

where `func()` is where you create and show the chart.

Answer (score -3):

You need to write `[STAThread]` before your `Main`

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
```

Comment: This code is for console application. The question is about winforms

Comment: Question is belongs to window forms not console.